# Identify word is plural or singular in iOS

Tags: ios, dictionary, nsstring, uitextchecker

I am checking words typed by users. I want to get unique words. For checking if the word is valid or not I am using following code:

```
UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *currentLanguage = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [word length]);

NSRange misspelledRange = [checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:word range: searchRange startingAt:0 wrap:NO language: currentLanguage];
if (misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound) // valid word
else // Invalid word
```

This is working well but the problem is it Identifies `Hand` and `Hands` as a different words as both are different in spell. I want to get only one which occurs first. I can't check with the `s` as the last character as `I` and `Is` are really different.

Is there any way to get identify the singular or plural words?

If I have any word can I get it's plural and singular word?

Thanks.

Comment: probably you'll need a dictionary/vocabulary which contains all well-known words with their plurals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All plural word doesn't suffice `s` or `es` to their singular part.

So the answer is **NO**.

Comment: What about foot/feet etc.?

Answer (score 0):

There are many exceptions using that rule. You need a third party/external vocabulary which contains all well-known words with their singular and plural variants.